# Observer Error In Magento

Tags: magento2

i am using `sales_order_save_after` event and getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have
>   not been committed or rolled back in
>   D:\wamp64\www\qsdev\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php
>   on line 3774

Comment: You may use "sales_order_place_before" event, or add observer code for better understanding for developers

Comment: I think some columns missing in sales_order table please check.